# add repeating strings value in json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON as

```
var newJSON = [{
    "key": "India",
    "value": "72"
}, {
    "key": "India",
    "value": "27"
}, {
    "key": "Pakistan",
    "value": "90"
}, {
    "key": "Zimbamwe",
    "value": "88"
}, {
    "key": "India",
    "value": "100"
}, {
    "key": "Pakistan",
    "value": "172"
}]
```

I want desired result as below, where the duplicate `key` values have their `value` properties added together:

```
[{
    "key": "India",
    "value": "199"
}, {
    "key": "Pakistan",
    "value": "262"
}, {
    "key": "Zimbamwe",
    "value": "88"
}]
```

Please help me with this

Comment: and where is the problem?

Comment: you need to group the results, but what the criteria? How to group different values for let's say India?

Comment: I thing the values are cumulating, but where is the question? what have you tried?

Comment: At least you should try your best and show what have you struggled with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
var grouped = [];
var added = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var indexOfCountry = added.indexOf(json[i].key);
    if (indexOfCountry >= 0)
    {
        grouped[indexOfCountry].value = (Number(grouped[indexOfCountry].value) + Number(json[i].value)).toString();
    }
    else {
        grouped.push(json[i]);
        added.push(json[i].key);
    }
}
```

`grouped` array is your desired result.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zummw9zp/

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for `reduce`, which is designed to take arrays and somehow, well, "reduce" them to other things, by looping across them and transforming the result at each iteration.

```
return newJSON.reduce(function(result, entry) {
    key = entry.key;
    result[key] = result[key] || { key: key, value: 0 };
    result[key].value += entry.value;
    return result;
}, {});
```

#### Using Underscore

If you're OK with using a library like Underscore, you can write this as

```
_.mapObject(_.groupBy(newJSON, 'key'), total)
```

Using a narrative style where we describe

```
`A(B, C)`
```

as

> Take `B` and do `A` to it using`C`

and

```
`A(B(C))`
```

as

> Take `C` and do `B` to it. Then take the result and do `A` to it

we can almost read this as English:

> Take **`newJSON`** and **group it by** using **`key`**. Then take the result and **map the object** using **`total`**

`_.groupBy` produces an object keyed by some property and returns groups, which are arrays of all the entries falling into each group:

```
{ 
  India: [ {key: "India", value: 72}, {key: "India", value: 100... ],
  ...
}
```

`total` calculates the total value for each group:

```
function total(group) { return sum(group . map(value)); }
```

So it converts an array of entries

```
[ {key: "India", value: 72}, {key: "India", value: 100}, ... ],
```

into 199. We use this to map the arrays of entries to total scores using `_.mapObject`.

Here `sum` can be written as

```
function sum(array)   { return array.reduce(add); }
function add(a, b)    { return a+b; }
```

and `value` is a little utility function to retrieve the `value` property:

```
function value(entry) { return entry.value; }
```

So the complete solution is:

```
function add   (a, b)  { return a+b;                     }
function sum   (array) { return array.reduce(add);       }
function value (entry) { return entry.value;             }
function total (group) { return sum(group . map(value)); }

_.mapObject(_.groupBy(newJSON, 'key'), total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var result = newJSON.reduce(function(acc, el){
  var val = acc.map[el.key];
  if(!val){
    acc.map[el.key] = val = { key:el.key, value: parseInt(el.value) };
    acc.result.push(val);
  }else{
    val.value += parseInt(el.value);
  }
  return acc;
},{map:{}, result:[]}).result;
```

```js
var newJSON = [
    {"key":"India","value":"72"},{"key":"India","value":"27"},
    {"key":"Pakistan","value":"90"},{"key":"Zimbamwe","value":"88"},
    {"key":"India","value":"100"},{"key":"Pakistan","value":"172"}
];

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = 'newJSON: ' + JSON.stringify(newJSON);

var result = newJSON.reduce(function(acc, el){
  var val = acc.map[el.key];
  if(!val){
    acc.map[el.key] = val = { key:el.key, value: parseInt(el.value) };
    acc.result.push(val);
  }else{
    val.value += parseInt(el.value);
  }
  return acc;
},{map:{}, result:[]}).result;

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML += '<br /><br />result: ' + JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```